# Update a form from Redux store update initiated from another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, redux, setstate

I'm so sorry if the question feels familiar, I've been searching StackOverflow for a day before posting this but haven't found an answer matching my needs.

I have 2 components : Form and List.
Form is a simple form used to register new users (name, firstName, email, password).
List is showing the list of users that have been added using the Form.

In this list is a table showing users' IDs, names, first names, and emails, and then two buttons to update or delete a user. Delete is working like a charm, but update behaves weirdly.

When clicking the update button, that calls an action from the Redux store to fire, which asks the database for the complete info of the selected user (through axios), ID included.

This update to the userToUpdate state in the store causes a rerender of the Form component, which displays all of the user's information in the form. BUT when clicking submit right away, the form tells me that all fields are empty. And when clicking on the update button twice and then the submit button, the form submits with data from the first update button click. Additionally, when clicking the fields (triggering an onChange function that handles the form local state), and then submitting, the error disappears and the correct data is sent.

Does anyone have an idea as to why, when updating my store, the data displays correctly, but is only really accessible by the form on the second update button click OR after having clicked every form input?

Here's the code for my Form and List components, do not hesitate to tell me if you need more :)

Form.js

```
import axios from 'axios';
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';

function Form() {
    const [message, setMessage] = useState([]);
    const userToUpdate = useSelector(state => state.userToUpdate);
    const [formUser, setFormUser] = useState({...userToUpdate});

    useEffect(() => {
        setFormUser({...userToUpdate});
    }, [userToUpdate])
    
    const onChange = e => {
        setFormUser({
            ...formUser,
            [e.target.id]: e.target.value
        })
    }

    const empty = e => {
            e.target.value = "";
    }

    const { register, handleSubmit, watch, formState: { errors } } = useForm();
    const onSubmit = (data) => {
        console.log(data);
        axios.post("http://localhost:8080/", data)
        .then(response => {
            setMessage([{
                type: "success",
                content: response.data
            }]);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            setMessage(error.response.data);
            setMessage([{
                type: "danger",
                content: error.response.data
            }]);
        });
    }

    return (
        <form className='w-25 p-4 mx-auto my-3 border border-success rounded' onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
            <div className="mb-3">
                <label htmlFor="nom" className="form-label">Nom</label>
                <input type="text" className={"form-control" + (errors.nom ? " is-invalid" : "")} id="nom" {...register("nom", {required: true, maxLength: 30})} value={formUser.nom} onChange={onChange} />
                {errors.nom && <span className='text-danger'><em>Nom</em> est requis (30 caractères max.)</span>}
            </div>
            <div className="mb-3">
                <label htmlFor="prenom" className="form-label">Prénom</label>
                <input type="text" className={"form-control" + (errors.prenom ? " is-invalid" : "")} id="prenom" {...register("prenom", {required: true, maxLength: 30})} value={formUser.prenom} onChange={onChange} />
                {errors.prenom && <span className='text-danger'><em>Prénom</em> est requis (30 caractères max.)</span>}
            </div>
            <div className="mb-3">
                <label htmlFor="email" className="form-label">Email</label>
                <input type="email" className={"form-control" + (errors.email ? " is-invalid" : "")} id="email" {...register("email", {required: true, maxLength: 50})} value={formUser.email} onChange={onChange} />
                {errors.email && <span className='text-danger'><em>Email</em> est requis (50 caractères max.)</span>}
            </div>
            <div className="mb-3">
                <label htmlFor="password" className="form-label">Password</label>
                <input type="password" className={"form-control" + (errors.password ? " is-invalid" : "")} id="password" {...register("password", {required: true, maxLength: 30})} value={formUser.password} onChange={onChange} onClick={(event) => {if(event.target.value.length > 30){empty(event)}}} />
                {errors.password && <span className='text-danger'><em>Password</em> est requis (30 caractères max.)</span>}
            </div>
            <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            {message.length > 0 ? <><div className={'alert mt-3 mb-0 alert-' + (message && message[0].type)}>{message[0].content}<a type="button" href="/" className={'d-block mx-auto mt-2 btn btn-' + (message && message[0].type)}>Recharger</a></div></> : <></>}
        </form>
    )
}

export default Form
```

List.js

```
import axios from 'axios'
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { actionCreators } from "../redux/index";
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';

function List() {
    const [usersList, setUsersList] = useState([]);
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const AC = bindActionCreators(actionCreators, dispatch);

    useEffect(() => {
        getUsersList();
    },[]);

    const getUsersList = async() => {
        const getUsers = await axios.get("http://localhost:8080/");
        setUsersList(getUsers.data);
    }

    const deleteUser = async(id) => {
        console.log(id);
        axios.delete("http://localhost:8080/", {params: {id: id}})
        .then(response => {
            getUsersList();
        })
        .catch(error => {

        });
    }

    return (
        <div className='w-50 p-4 mx-auto my-3 border border-success rounded'>
            <h2>Liste des utilisateurs</h2>
            {usersList.length <= 0 ? <h4 className='text-center'>Aucun utilisateur</h4> : 
                <table className="table table-striped">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="col">#</th>
                            <th scope="col">Nom</th>
                            <th scope="col">Prenom</th>
                            <th scope="col">Email</th>
                            <th scope="col">Upd.</th>
                            <th scope="col">Supp</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {usersList.map(element => {
                            return (
                                <tr className='align-middle' key={element.id}>
                                    <th scope="row">{element.id}</th>
                                    <td>{element.nom}</td>
                                    <td>{element.prenom}</td>
                                    <td>{element.email}</td>
                                    <td><a className='btn btn-warning' onClick={() => AC.updateUser(element.id)}><i className="bi bi-pencil-fill"></i></a></td>
                                    <td><a className='btn btn-danger' onClick={() => deleteUser(element.id)}><i className="bi bi-trash3-fill"></i></a></td>
                                </tr>
                            )
                        })}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            }
        </div>
        
    )
}

export default List
```

Here's the UI for context:
[UI screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MiisP.png)

I tried storing the store data in a local state, to use the spread operator to set the local form state to a shallow copy of the store data, to wait for setFormUser to finish before ending the useEffect block, etc.

Comment: Can you post your Redux files? or share you github repo for us to see?

Comment: Sure, here you go :)
https://github.com/charlesfouquet/projet-recap-spring-react/tree/redux